# How to convert date format in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

I am getting xml response date format string is "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a" but I need convert other date format ""dd MMM yy HH:mm"".
How to convert date format in vb.net? Please give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you want to convert the xml string value to a proper `DateTime` variable, Net has many methods for this:

```
' a date value in the string format specified:
Dim xmlDate As String = "07/15/2014 7:07:33 AM"

' create a DATE variable from that string in a known format:
Dim newDate As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(xmlDate, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
           Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Once you have am actual date variable, you can display it in any format required.  Doing so does not change the underlying date value, it just changes the output style:

```
Dim myDt As DateTime = DateTime.Now

Console.WriteLine(mydt.ToString("dd MMM yy HH:mm tt"))
Console.WriteLine(mydt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss"))
```

`DateTime` types are a *value*; they do not have a format. Formats are for how we display data to humans (as with `.ToString()` above) and how we tell `DataTime` the pattern to expect when parsing text data from humans into a `DateTime` variable.

You must be careful when using many of the VB functions.  Some do not create date types at all, just new string variables.  `CDate` can be especially problematic when using date strings from other cultures .  It assumes the string is in the current culture format, which may not be the case.  This can lead to `08/07/yyyy` converting to `07/08/yyyy`.

---

From original question:
    `I am getting xml response date format string is "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"`

From comment:
    `xml returning date format is "7/8/2014 12:00:00 PM"`

The format specified in the question **does not match** the example posted in the comment.  The xmlDate text is in fact in `M/d/yyyy` format, not `MM/dd/yyyy`!  Using `ParseExact` means we are giving `DateTime` the **exact** format to expect.  When the format does **not** match the actual string pattern, it will fail:

```
Dim actualDate As Date
Dim xmlTest As String = "7/8/2014 12:00:00 PM"

actualDate = DateTime.ParseExact(xmlSource, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                                 Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This will fail because the text is not in `MM/dd` format.  Note that `"M/d"` **can** parse dates from strings in the pattern of `"MM/dd"` because some days and months will be 2 characters ("10/20...").  But the reverse is not true: "MM/dd" will require the leading `0`.  Specify the correct format and you wont get a format exception:

```
 actualDate = DateTime.ParseExact(xmlSource, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                                 Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

---

---

`ParseExact` is probably the best approach here, because it appears you are importing data from elsewhere.  For simple data validation of user input, `Parse` or `TryParse` are usually enough.  These will try to parse the text using *any of the format patterns* defined for the current culture.

Some [cultures have well over 100](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WImdZ7).  This means the user can input date data almost anyway they want and your code can still parse/convert it to a `DateTime` type.

See [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: +1 for using ParseExact and InvariantCulture. Well said all around

Comment: hi xml returning date format is "7/8/2014 12:00:00 PM" above steps i am folowing its returning errorSystem.FormatException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  Source=mscorlib

Comment: see edit - you did not correctly describe your problem in the original question, so the code cannot be just cut and pasted.  @NarasimhaKolla

Comment: hi friend,i edited my question and understood the problem what i made. i will improve my self .Thank you very much for your kind support.issue is clear

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim theirTime = "07/15/2014 1:43:38 PM"
Dim myFormat = "dd MMM yy HH:mm"

Dim myTime = Format(CDate(theirTime), myFormat)
```

Comment: Their time format can be "dd/MM/yyyy" or "MM/dd/yyyy". For example "11/12/2019". Is "12", day or month? I think it could be a Problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now  'Your date
Dim format As String = "dd MMM yy HH:mm"
Dim newdate = time.ToString(format)
```

Comment: This is the only option that worked, without having to add a culture - which was causing a crash each time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim dat As Date
Dim dd, mm, yyyy As String

DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1)

If Len(DateTimePicker1.Value.Day) = 2 Then
    dd = DateTimePicker1.Value.Day
Else
    dd = "0" & DateTimePicker1.Value.Day
End If

If Len(DateTimePicker1.Value.Month) = 2 Then
    mm = DateTimePicker1.Value.Month
Else
    mm = "0" & DateTimePicker1.Value.Month
End If

yyyy = DateTimePicker1.Value.Year

dat = dd & "/" & mm & "/" & yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim CommenceDateFormat As Date = 
    Date.ParseExact(CommenceDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) 'converts date to a format understood for comparisons
Dim EndDateFormat As Date = 
    Date.ParseExact(EndDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)  Instead of just posting some lines of code, please always add an explanation of that code to your answer. Otherwise it might be classifed as incomplete and might be removed.