# How can I display a "dd/mm/yyyy" date as a "yyyy-mm-dd" date

Tags: vb.net, string, date, datetime

I keep seeing similar questions for Python and PHP, but I don't have access to those functions since I'm not using either of them. The language I'm using is VB.NET. So if I have:

```
Dim date1 = "06/19/2015"
```

then I want to convert it to

```
"2015-06-19"
```

I can replace to "/" character using Replace() really easily, but I can't figure out how to order the day, month, and year around without it being too complex. Again, lots of similar questions on the web, but I'm having trouble finding one on that isn't using Python and PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert date format in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755940/how-to-convert-date-format-in-vb-net)

Comment: Why do you have the `date1` as a `string` in the first place? there is a `DateTime` structure in .Net that you should use.

Comment: Thanks, I never found this question. I'll begin looking into it.

Comment: @Zohar Peled I have to download it as a string via SQL and convert it to DateTime later.

Comment: is it stored in sql as a string or as a date / datetime value?

Comment: It depends which table I'm downloading from. In this case, it's almost definitely a date value.

Comment: If it's a datetime, then why are you using a string?  In Sql datetimes do not have a format, they are simply a datetime value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build up a list of possible formats and use `DateTime.TryParseExact()`.  Then pass your desired output format to `DateTime.ToString()`.

```
    Dim date1 As String = "06/19/2015"
    Dim allowedFormats() As String = {"M/d/yy", "M/dd/yy", "MM/d/yy", "MM/dd/yy", "M/d/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy", "MM/d/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy"}
    Dim dt As DateTime
    If DateTime.TryParseExact(date1, allowedFormats, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
        Dim date2 As String = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        Debug.Print(date1 & " --> " & date2)
    End If
```