# What is the proper date format for this value?

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, datetime-format

I know how to use ParseExact which is passed a date as a string plus the date format as a string. I can't seem to figure out the proper format for my date and was hoping to get some help.

First the code:

```
For Each row In qryDays

   Dim strFloweredDate As String = row.Field(Of String)("FloweredDate")
   MessageBox.Show(strFloweredDate)
   Dim FloweringDate As Date
   FloweringDate = Date.ParseExact(strFloweredDate, "M/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

   ' Also tried the following formats
   ' Dim FloweringDate As Date
   ' FloweringDate = Date.ParseExact(strFloweredDate, "M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
   ' Dim FloweringDate As Date
   ' FloweringDate = Date.ParseExact(strFloweredDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
   ' Dim FloweringDate As Date
   ' FloweringDate = Date.ParseExact(strFloweredDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
   ' Dim FloweringDate As DateTime
   ' FloweringDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strFloweredDate, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
   ' Dim FloweringDate As DateTime
   ' FloweringDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strFloweredDate, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
   ' ETC ETC ETC

Next
```

Now two photos. One of the Messagebox results showing the date and the other is the error:

[image: Date in string format]

[image: ParseExact Error Two]

If anyone could help me chose the right date/time format I would be most grateful.

Thank you!

Comment: If you use `ParseExact`, you must specify the **exact** format.  The text clearly includes a time segment which all your format strings ignore.  it may well work to use `TryParse` and let it try to parse from maybe 100+ formats defined for the given culture.    possible duplicate of [How to convert date format in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755940/how-to-convert-date-format-in-vb-net)

Comment: Plutonix The last two examples show using DateTime instead of date with me adding a time section. Why are you claiming a duplicate when I know how to convert it I just don't have the specific format, which you did not provide?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the time portion was incomplete - no AM/PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say:

> M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt

Where `tt` is the AM/PM designator.

See: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

In order to make sure you are getting it right with the d/M <-> M/d issue, you can also use `TryParse` and pass it the correct culture:

```
DateTime result;
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, culture, styles, out result)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: You are the MAN Olivier Jascot-Descombes! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us what `row` is, but given that it came from `qryDays`, I will guess that it is coming from a record in a database.  It's probably a `System.Data.DataRow`.  If so, there's a good chance that your data is *already* in a `DateTime` type, and thus you should not go through a `String` to use it.

Try:

```
Dim FloweredDate As DateTime = row.Field(Of DateTime)("FloweredDate");
```

Keep in mind that the `Date` keyword in VB.net is an alias for `System.DateTime`, so these types are equivalent.