# Formatting date parameter in VBScript

Tags: .net, vb.net, parameters, date-formatting

I was wondering if someone can assist me with accomplishing the following task:

I am looking to have a parameter change format to `YYYYMMDD`.  As of right now the parameter is a string and is in this format; "2013-10-15 11:48:00.000".  So, I am looking to strip off the time and just have the above date read; "20131015" (no quotes).

```
Dim strDateScanned As String = dtb.Rows(N).Item(11).ToString
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@User1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15)
myCommand.Parameters("@User1").Value = strDateScanned
```

The parameter field I wish to change to YYYYMMDD is @User1.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This does look like VB.Net not VBScript, can you confirm what you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert date format in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24755940/692942)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm using VBScript, and I reliably get Date/Time in that format, I'm likely to Split on " ", and replace the "-" chars.

```
FormattedDate = Replace(Split(strDateScanned, " ")(0), "-", "")
```

Hope this doesn't make anyone mad.

Comment: If it is VBScript then it's a duplicate question, so answering isn't the cleverest thing to do, is it? Do you notice any of the comments left on the question?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the following?

```
Format(CDate(strDateScanned), "yyyyMMdd")
```

(or start with the DateTime value instead of converting to String)

```
Format(DateScanned, "yyyyMMdd")
```

Hope this helps!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bz1f0h(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: You realise that is VB.Net and not VBScript?

Comment: You did notice that he's assigning variables as he dimensions them, right? Not a very VBScript behavior. I see the tag, but not everyone uses them correctly. Do you think there might have been a way for you to comment, and raise a flag, without being insulting and arrogant?

Comment: How about instead of answering blindly you change the tag then, why leave it to someone else?

Comment: You are right it does look like VB.Net, not sure What I was on when I looked at the code. But regardless it's still a duplicate.