# DateTime format as "Fri, 14 Oct 2011 23:10:10 -0000"

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datetime-format

I try to use vb.net to get this format for now().
can you please help me how to do this .
it is not a supported format here
[Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What is the purpose of -0000? It is always fixed at -0000?

Comment: @steve yes i think it is always 0000

Comment: @Rakitić sorry i missed something on copy

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss -0000") ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert date format in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755940/how-to-convert-date-format-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim date1 As Date = #10/14/2011 11:10:10PM#
    Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("ddd, d MMM yyyy H:mm:ss -0000", _
              CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")))
End Sub
```

Output:

> Fri, 14 Oct 2011 23:10:10 -0000

See the <kbd>[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iTYzAo)</kbd>