# Converting one unknown DatePattern to a known pattern

Tags: vb.net

I get the user machine's date pattern using this:

```
Dim sysFormat As String = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

so for example it comes as `M/d/yy`  but in my program I want to parse them in a `M/d/yyyy` format.   But they could even have some other format, we don't know what format. It is **ALWAYS** gonna be US English tho.

So is there a way to automatically convert whatever it is to the `M/d/yyyy` format ? or do I have to manually do some string processing code and split the string to different parts for day,month, year?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755940/how-to-convert-date-format-in-vb-net

Comment: Dates dont have a format, they are just a number.  Formats are just how they are displayed to users so they understand it.  If you are asking about parsing dates, changing the `ShortDatePattern` wont change anything and you can specify patterns if you want

Comment: A date comes in in some format. I want to always output it in some specific format.  That's my question.

Comment: @KSNoob `A date comes in in some format.` then you have to parse it accordingly to convert to DateTime. Once you have datetime object you can output in any format you have.

Comment: *strings* comes in some format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried formatting your String to a Datetime object and then parsing using a specific formatter?

```
Dim myDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(sysFormat, "M/d/yyyy", 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

And your new String (the one that's formatted) is:

```
Dim formattedStringDate As String = myDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

The requirements you have seem quite specific. You could use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to try parsing a few valid formats and check whether any results in a valid date. With new C# features you could even get rid of the extra out-parameter declaration. For example:

```cs
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime, 
                       "M/d/yy", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       DateTime out dt);
```