# String Foramting vb.net

Tags: string, vb.net

i want to display date value like '2020/03/30' as '20200330'
i tried this code

Date.Now.Year & Date.Now.Month & Date.Now.day

but this returns 2020330
how can this return 20200330 ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert date format in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755940/how-to-convert-date-format-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating numbers, which get implicitly converted to strings.

You could check out [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

In your case, this might do just fine: `Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`

By the way, as @jmcilhinney already commented to your question, you could easily find such basic information by using your favorite search engine on the internet...

Comment: Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")